# Showing order of accuracy of numerical method for $1$-dimensional wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, approximation, wave-equation

Consider the numerical routine:

$$\frac{1}{\Delta t^2} (U_i^{n+1} -2U_i^{n} + U_i^{n-1}) - \frac{a^2}{\Delta x^2} (U_{i+1}^{n} -2U_i^{n} + U_{i-1}^{n})$$

which solves the $1$-dimensional wave equation $$u_{tt} - a^2 u_{xx} = 0$$ where a $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $U_i^n$ is the numerical approximation of $u(j\Delta x,n\Delta t)$.

So my book mentions multiple times that this numerical scheme is second-order accurate. It kind of passingly mentions this with really saying how I would go about actually showing it, nor can I find any example of how to do so. The only thing it says is that

> a truncation error analysis reveals second-order accuracy.

I tried looking this up and again I'm having a difficult time seeing what exactly it is I need to do. I think I need to perform a Taylor expansion but I don't know around which variables this needs to happen or where to evaluate it. I would appreciate it if someone could show how this is second order accurate or provide some references of where I would learn how to do so. It's something that keeps popping up.

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: Is this finite differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the spatial derivative (dropping the time index for convenience).  Using the 4th order Taylor expansion we have

$$U_{i+1} = U_i + U_{x,i} \Delta x + \frac{1}{2}U_{xx,i}\Delta x^2 + \frac{1}{6}U_{xxx,i}\Delta x^3 + O(\Delta x^4), \\ U_{i-1} = U_i - U_{x,i} \Delta x + \frac{1}{2}U_{xx,i}\Delta x^2 - \frac{1}{6}U_{xxx,i}\Delta x^3 + O(\Delta x^4). $$

Adding the two equations, we get

$$U_{i+1} + U_{i-1} =2U_i + U_{xx,i}\Delta x^2 + O(\Delta x^4).$$

Rearrranging,

$$\frac{U_{i+1} -2U_i + U_{i-1}}{\Delta x^2} = U_{xx,i} + O(\Delta x^2).$$

This shows the truncation error associated with the central difference approximation of the second partial derivative is of second order. A similar result is obtained for the second partial derivative with respect to the time variable.

Comment: Interesting, so I have some follow up questions. (1) In general, do we only need to consider one of the derivatives (here you did x instead of t) to show the order of accuracy? And (2) is the idea of simply taking a taylor expansion of the backward and forward time steps and then adding them basically what underlies truncation error?

Comment: @John Alberto:  The first answer is no, the second is yes.  You also do the same analysis for the approximation to the time derivative.

Comment: In this way the approximation to the PDE operator has a total error that is of order $O(\Delta x^2) + O(\Delta t^2)$ which converges to $0$ as the mesh is refined.  In this way it is said that the difference approximation is "consistent."

Comment: All of this assumes that the solution is smooth with bounded derivatives up to the 4th order.

Comment: So what you're saying is that when I do the same analysis for the time derivative and also see that it's second order, that's what makes it consistent.

Thank you for the very clear explanations! The entire process was much more simple than I thought!

Comment: Consistency does not mean both errors have to be of the same order. It means that the overall error converges to 0 as $\Delta x \to 0$ and $\Delta t \to 0.$ In this case, though, both happen to be second-order accurate.