# Rigorous definition of space and time order of accuracy of numerical PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose that we are solving numerically a PDE (with a numerical scheme like this one: [Showing order of accuracy](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996498)) which involves space $x$ and time $t.$ It is a commonly seen expression in the literature that "the method has order of accuracy $a$ in time, and order $b$ in space".

However the meaning of this statement is never defined clearly in any place I see. For instance, if the local error is $\delta x^4 + \delta x^2 \delta t+\delta t^3,$ is the method 2nd order in time? The $\delta t^3$ term has power 3 but $\delta x^3 \delta t$ only has power 1 in $\delta t$!

Similarly, is the method 3rd order in $x$?

**What's the strict definition of "the method has order of accuracy $a$ in time, and order $b$ in space"???**